# which input cause this sql exception An unexpected token "" was found following "". Expected tokens may include:?

Tags: java, sql, db2

There is one web page in our application which allows the user to input something then we add the input to the sql to access the DB. 
The SQL is like below:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    AA_BBBB_CCC_DD_EEEEEADAY_XXX_YYY
WHERE
    (
        AA_BBBB_CCC_DD_EEEEEADAY_XXX_YYY.GGGG_NAME LIKE '%USER_INPUT%')
AND (
        AA_BBBB_CCC_DD_EEEEEADAY_XXX_YYY.FFF_DATE >= '2016-12-30 00:00:00.000'
    AND AA_BBBB_CCC_DD_EEEEEADAY_XXX_YYY.FFF_DATE < '2016-12-31 00:00:00.000' )
AND ( (
            AA_BBBB_CCC_DD_EEEEEADAY_XXX_YYY.HHHH_NO = '00018001410000'
        AND AA_BBBB_CCC_DD_EEEEEADAY_XXX_YYY.HHHH_CCY = 'XXX'))
AND 1=1
AND (
        ZZZ_DATE >= '2016-06-01 00:00:00.000')
ORDER BY
    11 DESC
```

**USER_INPUT** can be any string input by the user. in this case it's `%USER_INPUT%`, sometimes maybe `USER_INPUT%`.

Now there is one exception in our log,

> An unexpected token "=" was found following "ADAY_XXX_YYY.HHHH_NO". 
>   Expected tokens may include:  ") ".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601,
>   DRIVER=3.64.82

my guess is user input some string destroy the valid sql and cause `ADAY_XXX_YYY.HHHH_NO =` broken. As i test it's easy to get the `YY.GGGG_NAME LIKE` broken by just add **'** in the input string, but cannot figure out what kind of input could cause the `ADAY_XXX_YYY.HHHH_NO` broken. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please learn about [Little Bobby Tables](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/Little_Bobby_Tables). AS soon as someone is able to perform SQL injection, they can do pretty much as they please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is SQL injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832938/what-is-sql-injection)

Comment: you must double quote into your user_input variable. Replace quote by double quote